# Why is this C++ wrapper class not being inlined away?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, assembly, compilation

**EDIT** - something's up with my build system.  I'm still figuring out exactly what, but `gcc` was producing weird results (even though it's a `.cpp` file), but once I used `g++` then it worked as expected.

---

This is a very reduced test-case for something I've been having trouble with, where using a numerical wrapper class (which I thought would be inlined away) made my program 10x slower.

This is independent of optimisation level (tried with `-O0` and `-O3`).

Am I missing some detail in my wrapper class?

---

### C++

I have the following program, in which I define a class which wraps a `double` and provides the `+` operator:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#define INLINE __attribute__((always_inline)) inline

struct alignas(8) WrappedDouble {
    double value;

    INLINE friend const WrappedDouble operator+(const WrappedDouble& left, const WrappedDouble& right) {
        return {left.value + right.value};
    };
};

#define doubleType WrappedDouble // either "double" or "WrappedDouble"

int main() {
    int N = 100000000;
    doubleType* arr = (doubleType*)malloc(sizeof(doubleType)*N);
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i];
    }

    free(arr);
    printf("done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I thought that this would compile to the same thing - it's doing the same calculations, and everything is inlined.

However, it's not - it produces a larger and slower result, regardless of optimisation level.

(This particular result is not *significantly* slower, but my actual use-case includes more arithmetic.)

**EDIT** - I am aware that this isn't constructing my array elements.  I thought this might produce less ASM so I could understand it better, but I can change it if it's a problem.

**EDIT** - I am also aware that I should be using `new[]`/`delete[]`.  Unfortunately `gcc` refused to compile that, even though it was in a `.cpp` file.  This was a symptom of my build system being screwed up, which is probably my actual problem.

**EDIT** - If I use `g++` instead of `gcc`, it produces identical output.

---

**EDIT** - I posted the wrong version of the ASM (`-O0` instead of `-O3`), so this section isn't helpful.

### Assembly

I'm using XCode's gcc on my Mac, on a 64-bit system.  The result is the same, aside from the body of the for-loop.

Here's what it produces for the body of the loop if `doubleType` is `double`:

```
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
movl    -20(%rbp), %ecx
subl    $1, %ecx
movslq  %ecx, %rdx
movsd   (%rax,%rdx,8), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
movslq  -20(%rbp), %rdx
addsd   (%rax,%rdx,8), %xmm0
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
movslq  -20(%rbp), %rdx
movsd   %xmm0, (%rax,%rdx,8)
```

The `WrappedDouble` version is much longer:

```
movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
movl    -44(%rbp), %ecx
subl    $1, %ecx
movslq  %ecx, %rdx
shlq    $3, %rdx
addq    %rdx, %rax
movq    -40(%rbp), %rdx
movslq  -44(%rbp), %rsi
shlq    $3, %rsi
addq    %rsi, %rdx
movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
movq    %rdx, -24(%rbp)
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
movsd   (%rax), %xmm0           ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
addsd   (%rax), %xmm0
movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp)
movsd   -8(%rbp), %xmm0         ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
movsd   %xmm0, -56(%rbp)
movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
movslq  -44(%rbp), %rdx
movq    -56(%rbp), %rsi
movq    %rsi, (%rax,%rdx,8)
```

Comment: You should almost *never* use `malloc` in C++. It only allocates memory, but it doesn't construct objects. And almost never use `new[]` to allocate arrays, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: and a goto label...

Comment: Thanks for the code review - does that affect the way the body of my for-loop is compiling?

Comment: You have UB currently as reading uninitialized variables...

Comment: Returning `const` is a notorious optimisation killer.

Comment: Same timing with `std::vector` [Demo](http://quick-bench.com/UaSU2OONRvfchNh4LHQX-UpRyjI) :)

Comment: Using a vector and the `-O2` flag, using a `double` of your class [compiles to the same code](https://godbolt.org/z/FekrSf) (with GCC 8.2). Note that removing the `INLINE` macro or using "proper" type-aliases didn't change anything.

Comment: This is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Let's assume that I have a good reason for wanting to work with a raw pointer - in this particular case, my actual code works with an SDK that passes me a raw pointer.

Comment: Using `new[]` makes the generated code smaller, but still the same for both types: https://godbolt.org/z/r0FxBQ

Comment: @MarekR No it's not

Comment: What I've learned so far is that my problem goes away if I'm using `g++` instead of `gcc`.  I'm surprised, because I thought they'd be the same when compiling "demo.cpp".

Comment: @cloudfeet I would not have any expectations regarding code compilation if you have obvious undefined behavior. If the compiler can prove that your code is UB (which is not hard in this case), it  is free to emit literally anything, from an empty executable to an `rm -rf /` call. See [UB can result in time travel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: @molbdnilo How so?

Comment: The asm code you've put here is from a non-optimized build, so it is completely useless. Put asm code here, which is from an optimized build. "inlined away": what do you mean by this? `operator+` is inlined, even in non-optimized builds, just as you requested it by using the `always_inline` attribute.

Comment: OK, something is screwed up with my build system.  I was attempting to compile with `gcc` - however, even though it was compiling `main.cpp`, it was throwing a fit about `new` and `delete`, which is why I'd fallen back to using malloc.

Comment: @geza - I tried it with optimisation on and off - it gave me longer results both times.  However, that was for `gcc` (which was also refusing to compile `new`/`delete[]`).  When I used `g++`, it worked as everyone else here described - and then `gcc` started working identically as well.

Comment: @cloudfeet: A longer result doesn't necessarily mean longer running time. Put optimized asm build here, as there is no point comparing non-optimized builds performance-wise.

Comment: The optimised version also ran slower (faster than the unoptimised version, but slower than the version without the wrapper), by about 10%.  I don't have the original outputs anymore - and ever since I tried `g++`, `gcc` started behaving properly and won't give me the same results I saw originally.  Sorry. :/

Comment: IIRC, `gcc` on a `.cpp` file will compile it as C++, but since you used the `gcc` front-end it won't link the C++ standard library.  So you'll get a link error if you use `new` instead of `malloc`.  There's no good reason to ever use `gcc` on C++ code AFAIK, that's just what happens if you do so by accident.  Of course you probably have a `gcc` that's actually Apple `clang`, but probably the behaviour is the same.

Comment: BTW, if you want to actually speed this up, see the Prefix Sum links in my answer.  It is possible to use SIMD for this, especially with AVX, but the compiler won't auto-vectorize it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions result in identical assembly code with `g++` and `clang++` when you turn on optimizations with `-O3`.

Comment: Thanks - I was using `-O3`, but I was using it with `gcc`.  I compiled with `g++` instead, and it worked.

Comment: The fact that `gcc` started producing different results after I'd run `g++` probably means something is interestingly, creatively wrong with my build environment.  I appreciate your help, even though it turned out to be a foolish question which got downvoted!

Comment: @cloudfeet: The asm output in your question is *clearly* from `-O0`.  The stores/reloads make it totally obvious.  See the commented optimized asm in my answer.  You could have also had a `-O0` on the command line, or `-O3` wasn't actually being passed to your compiler at all.  The 10x slower behaviour is also consistent with the asm you show for the two versions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, sorry - the one I posted was `-O0`.  However, the `-O3` code was still slower and longer for the wrapped version (but shorter and faster than `-O0`).  I should have posted that instead.  (Also, I was passing the arguments directly on the command-line.)

Answer (score 7):

**It *is* inlined, but not optimized away because you compiled with `-O0` (the default)**.  That generates asm for consistent debugging, allowing you to *modify* any C++ variable while stopped at a breakpoint on any line.

This means the compiler spills everything from registers after every statement, and reloads what it needs for the next.  So more statements to express the same logic = slower code, whether they're in the same function or not. 
 [Why does clang produce inefficient asm for this simple floating point sum (with -O0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-for-this-simple-floating-point-sum-with) explains in more detail.

Normally `-O0` won't inline functions, but it does respect `__attribute__((always_inline))`.

**[C loop optimization help for final assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/c-loop-optimization-help-for-final-assignment/32001196#32001196) explains why benchmarking or tuning with `-O0` is totally pointless.**  Both versions are ridiculous garbage for performance.

---

**If it wasn't inlined, there'd be a `call` instruction that called it inside the loop.**

The asm is actually creating the pointers in registers for `const WrappedDouble& left` and `right`.  (very inefficiently, using multiple instructions instead of one `lea`.  The `addq    %rdx, %rax` is the final step in one of those.)

Then it spills those pointer args to stack memory, because they're real variables and have to be in memory where a debugger could modify them.  That's what `movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)` and `%rdx` ... is doing.

After reloading and dereferencing those pointers, the `addsd` (add scalar double) result is itself spilled back to a local in stack memory with `movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp)`.  This isn't a named variable, it's the return value of the function.

It's then reloaded and copied again to another stack location, then finally `arr` and `i` are loaded from the stack, along with the `double` result of `operator+`, and that's stored into `arr[i]` with `movq    %rsi, (%rax,%rdx,8)`.  (Yes, LLVM used a 64-bit integer `mov` to copy a `double` that time.  The earlier times used SSE2 `movsd`.)

**All of those copies of the return value are on the critical path for the loop-carried dependency chain, because the next iteration reads `arr[i-1]`.**  Those ~5 or 6 cycle store-forwarding latencies really add up vs. 3 or 4 cycle FP `add` latency.

---

Obviously that's *massively* inefficient.  **With optimization enabled, gcc and clang have no trouble inlining and optimizing away your wrapper.**

They also optimize by keeping around the `arr[i]` result in a register for use as the `arr[i-1]` result in the next iteration.  This avoids the ~6 cycle store-forwarding latency that would otherwise be inside the loop, if it made asm like the source.

i.e. the optimized asm looks kind of like this C++:

```
double tmp = arr[0];   // kept in XMM0

for(...) {
   tmp += arr[i];   // no re-read of mmeory
   arr[i] = tmp;
}
```

**Amusingly, clang doesn't bother to initialize its `tmp` (`xmm0`) before the loop, because you don't bother to initialize the array**.  Strange it doesn't warn about UB.  In practice a big `malloc` with glibc's implementation will give you fresh pages from the OS, and they will all hold zeros, i.e. `0.0`.  But clang will give you whatever was left around in XMM0!  If you add a `((double*)arr)[0] = 1;`, clang will load the first element before the loop.

**Unfortunately the compiler doesn't know how to do any better than that for your Prefix Sum calculation.  See [parallel prefix (cumulative) sum with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse) and [SIMD prefix sum on Intel cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587598/simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu)** for ways to speed this up by another factor of maybe 2, and/or parallelize it.

I prefer Intel syntax, but [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdlib%3E%0A%0A%23define+INLINE+__attribute__((always_inline))+inline%0A%0Astruct+alignas(8)+WrappedDouble+%7B%0A++++double+value%3B%0A%0A++++INLINE+friend+const+WrappedDouble+operator%2B(const+WrappedDouble%26+left,+const+WrappedDouble%26+right)+%7B%0A++++++++return+%7Bleft.value+%2B+right.value%7D%3B%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%23define+doubleType+WrappedDouble+//+either+%22double%22+or+%22WrappedDouble%22%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+N+%3D+100000000%3B%0A++++doubleType*+arr+%3D+(doubleType*)malloc(sizeof(doubleType)*N)%3B%0A++++//+((double*)arr)%5B0%5D+%3D+1%3B%0A++++//+with+no+array+init,+clang+doesn!'t+bother+to+init+its+XMM0%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+1%3B+i+%3C+N%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++arr%5Bi%5D+%3D+arr%5Bi+-+1%5D+%2B+arr%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++free(arr)%3B%0A++++printf(%22done%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:30.50309915596882,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:36.16356751069786,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dhaswell+-Wall+-Wextra',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) can give you AT&T syntax like in your question if you like.

```
# gcc8.2 -O3 -march=haswell -Wall
.LC1:
    .string "done"
main:
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     edi, 800000000
    call    malloc                  # return value in RAX

    vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]   # load first elmeent
    lea     rdx, [rax+8]            # p = &arr[1]
    lea     rcx, [rax+800000000]    # endp = arr + len

.L2:                                   # do {
    vaddsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx]   # tmp += *p
    add     rdx, 8                        # p++
    vmovsd  QWORD PTR [rdx-8], xmm0       # p[-1] = tmp
    cmp     rdx, rcx
    jne     .L2                        # }while(p != endp);

    mov     rdi, rax
    call    free
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    puts
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

Clang unrolls a bit, and like I said doesn't bother to init its `tmp`.

```
# just the inner loop from clang -O3
# with -march=haswell it unrolls a lot more, so I left that out.
# hence the 2-operand SSE2 addsd instead of 3-operand AVX vaddsd
.LBB0_1:                                # do {
    addsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx - 16]
    movsd   qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx - 16], xmm0
    addsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx - 8]
    movsd   qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx - 8], xmm0
    addsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx]
    movsd   qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx], xmm0
    add     rcx, 3                            # i += 3
    cmp     rcx, 100000002
    jne     .LBB0_1                      } while(i!=100000002)
```

Apple XCode's `gcc` is really clang/LLVM in disguise, on modern OS X systems.

Comment: It's always a pleasure to read one of your answers. Amazing what difference a few comments in asm make!

Comment: @MaxLanghof: thanks, I'm glad someone enjoyed it.  I spent longer than I initially meant to writing an answer that basically says "don't use -O0". :P

Answer (score 1):

For future reference (mine and anyone else): I was seeing a few different things:

1. The XCode project I was using originally (which I adapted but didn't create) is somehow configured so that even the Release build wasn't using `-O3`.
2. Using `gcc` for C++ code is a bad idea.  Even when compiling a `.cpp` file, it doesn't link to the standard library by default.  Using `g++` is much smoother.
3. The most interesting (to me): even when the wrapper was inlining correctly, the wrapper *disrupted some optimisations*!

The third point was what caused the slowdown in my original code (not listed here) which led me down this path.

When you are adding a bunch of floating-point values, e.g. `a + b + c + d`, it isn't allowed to re-order `c` or `d` because (since floating-point values are approximate) that might produce a subtly different result.  However, it *is* allowed to swap `a` and `b`, because that first addition is symmetrical - and in my case, this let it use SIMD instructions on 64-bit builds.

However, when the wrapper was used, it didn't carry over the information that the first `+` is in fact commutative!  It dutifully inlined everything away, but somehow didn't realise it was still allowed to swap the first two arguments.  When I re-ordered the sums manually in the appropriate way, my two versions got equal performance.

Comment: Was that missed-optimization with `gcc -O2` instead of `-O3` or something?  That would have been a more interesting question than the un-optimized asm, if `arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i];` compiled differently than `arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i - 1];` with gcc or LLVM.