# Inline c++ method in assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, inline

Lets have a small class called *myClass*. I was interested how does look the difference in .asm when method is **inlined** or not. I made two programs, **with** and **without** *inline* keyword in cpp file, but the .asm output was the same. I know that the *inline* is just a hint for compiler, and with the high probability I was a victim of an optimization, but is it possible to see the difference on a small cpp example of inlined and not inlined method in asm?

h:

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

class myClass{
private:
  int a;
public:
  int getA() const;
};

#endif
```

cpp:

```
#include <class.h>
inline int myCLass::getA() const{
  return a;
};
```

main:

```
#include "class.h"

int main(){
    myClass a;
    a.getA();
    return 0;
}
```

gcc:

```
gcc -S -O0 main.cpp
```

asm output in both cases:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 14
    .globl  _main                   ## -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rdi
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    callq   __ZNK7myClass4getAEv
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function

.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: The compiler can ignore the `inline` directive and mostly will do so. The main reason for using `inline` in C++ is to specify linkage, not to tell the compiler what to do.

Comment: You want the gcc-specific `noinline` attribute. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474050/2945027

Comment: `inline` in the .cpp file is always wrong.

Comment: @SergeyA nonsense (your *always*). There are many good reasons for `inline`d functions in the .cpp file: those that are not exported (and not part of an interface implemented in that file), mostly living in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: @Walter if they're in an anonymous namespace they don't need to be marked `inline` as they'll only ever be defined once.

Comment: @Walter nonsense, looks like you do not understand the purpose of `inline` keyword. The non-exported functions should either be `static` or defined in anonymous namespace. `inline` keyword does not affect linkage, and as such, doesn't prevent functions from being exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -O0` doesn't enable `-finline-functions`, so even if the functions were in the same file it wouldn't try.  See also [Why is this C++ wrapper class not being inlined away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073295/why-is-this-c-wrapper-class-not-being-inlined-away/54074497#54074497).  (Don't bother trying to use `__attribute__((always_inline))`: you'll get inlining, things won't optimize away.

You could get things inlined with `gcc -O3 -fwhole-program *.cpp` to enable inlining across source files.  (Regardless of whether they were declared `inline` or not, it's just up to the compiler to decide what's best).

The main point of `inline` is to let the compiler know that it doesn't need to emit a stand-alone definition of a function if it does choose to inline it into all callers.  (Because a definition, not just a declaration, of this function will appear in all translation units that use it.  So if some other file decides not to inline it, a definition can be emitted there.)

Modern compilers still use their normal heuristics to decide whether it's worth inlining or not.  e.g. a large function with multiple callers will probably not be inlined, to avoid code bloat.  `static` tells the compiler that no other translation unit can see the function, so if there's only one caller in this file it will very likely inline there.  (If you have a large function, it's a bad idea to make it `static inline`.  You'll get a copy of the definition in each file where it doesn't inline, and too aggressive inlining.  For a small function that's probably going to inline everywhere, you should probably still just use `inline`, not `static inline`, so in case anything takes the address of the function there will only be one definition shared across all files.  `inline` tells the linker to merge duplicate definitions of a function instead of erroring.  This behaviour is one of the more important parts of what  `inline` really does, not the actual hint to the compiler that you want it to inline.)

---

`gcc -fwhole-program` (with all the source files on the same command line) gives the compiler enough information to make all these decision itself.  It can see if a function only has one caller across the whole program, and inline it instead of creating a stand-alone definition plus arg setup and a `call`.

`gcc -flto` allows link-time optimization similar to whole-program, but doesn't require all the `.cpp` files on the command line at once.  Instead it stores GIMPLE code in the `.o` files and finishes optimizing at link time.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't give the compiler a chance to inline `myClass::getA()` (as explained in another answer). To compare inline versus out-of-line methods, compare the usage of `getA()` and `getAlt()` in the code below

```
// file.h    
class myClass
{
    int a=1;
public:
    int getA() const { return a; }   // implicitly inline
    int getAlt() const;
};

// file.cc
#include "file.h"
int myClass::getAlt() const
{ return a; }

// main.cc
#include "file.h"
int main()
{
    myClass x;
    return x.getA() - x.getAlt();
}
```

You may use full optimizations except inter-procedural optimization (ipo; since that may allow the compiler to even inline `myClass::getAlt()`).

Answer (score 2):

For a function to be inlined reliably, the full definition of the function must be available in the translation unit that the call appears in.

Since the definition of `myClass::getA()` isn't visible to `main.c`, the function cannot be inlined. It might be inlined in any calls that appeared in `myClass.cpp`, but you don't have any of those.

To allow this function to be inlined, you will need to declare it as `inline` in the header file and include its definition, e.g.

```
class myClass {
  …
  inline int getA() const { return a; }
  …
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reliably"?

Comment: LTO exists, but is quite flaky because it doesn't know what annotations the programmer *intended* to be used safely across TUs.

Comment: FWIW the `inline` in your example is redundant.  inline member definitions are implicitly inline.

Answer (score 2):

The `inline` keyword has little to do with telling the compiler to inline calls to the function.  What `inline` does is allow the function to be *defined* inline in a header.

Using the `inline` keyword in a function definition allows the function to be defined in multiple translation units without violating the One Definition Rule so long as all of the definitions are identical.

Defining a function inline in a header can help the compiler inline calls to the function by allowing the full definition to be visible in multiple translation units, but that's all the `inline` keyword has to do with inlining calls.