# libsimdpp slower then debug gcc

Tags: c++, simd

I needed cross-platform SIMD instruction between arm and x86.  So i found a library called libsimdpp and ran this [example](https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp/blob/2e5c0464a8069310d7eb3048e1afa0e96e08f344/examples/vector-add.cpp).

I changed it a little to compare it to just a standard cpp approach for adding two arrays, but the libSimd example always performed worse.

Results

- 23 Milliseconds - libSimd
- 1 Milliseconds - normal cpp additation

Is this something wrong with the way I'm using the library or how it's built.

The changes i made to the example.

https://pastebin.com/L14DCrky

```
#define SIMDPP_ARCH_X86_SSE4_1 true
#include <simdpp/simd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
//example where i got this from
//https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp/tree/2e5c0464a8069310d7eb3048e1afa0e96e08f344

// Initializes vector to store values
void init_vector(float* a, float* b, size_t size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        a[i] = i * 1.0;
        b[i] = (size * 1.0) - i - 1;
    }
}



using namespace simdpp;
int main() {
    //1048576
    const unsigned long SIZE = 4 * 150000;

    float vec_a[SIZE];
    float vec_b[SIZE];
    float result[SIZE];

    ///////////////////////////*/
    //LibSIMDpp
    //*
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    init_vector(vec_a, vec_b, SIZE);
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i+=4) {
        float32<4> xmmA = load(vec_a + i);  //loads 4 floats into xmmA
        float32<4> xmmB = load(vec_b + i);  //loads 4 floats into xmmB
        float32<4> xmmC = add(xmmA, xmmB);  //Vector add of xmmA and xmmB
        store(result + i, xmmC);            //Store result into the vector
    }

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count()
              << " milliseconds\n";
    //*/


    ///////////////////////////*/
    //standard
    //*
    init_vector(vec_a, vec_b, SIZE);
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (auto i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        result[i] = vec_a[i]  + vec_b[i];
    }

    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count()
              << " milliseconds\n";
    //*/


    int i = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommend adding your build commands. It's mostly for completeness, but someone may spot an "Ooops!".

Comment: In the [example](https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp/tree/2e5c0464a8069310d7eb3048e1afa0e96e08f344/examples) there's a make file that I used.  The above code is just modified code from that example.

Comment: E.g., an "Ooops" like not enabling optimization ^^. Also for gcc: sometimes the main function does not get fully optimized. Try putting every performance critical code into a separate function. And have a look at the generated assembly (compile with `-O2 -S`)

Comment: Besides enabling optimization: In the first case you have `init_vector` inside the timing. This likely takes up more time than the addition afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal that a debug build slows down manually-vectorized code more than it slows down scalar even if you use `_mm_add_ps` intrinsics directly.  (Usually because you tend to use more separate statements, and debug code-gen compiles each statement separately.)

You're using a C++ wrapper library, so in debug mode that's a significant extra layer of stuff that *won't* optimize away because you told the compiler not to.  So it's not surprising that slows it down so much that it's worse than scalar.
 See [Why is this C++ wrapper class not being inlined away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073295/why-is-this-c-wrapper-class-not-being-inlined-away/54074497#54074497) for example.  (Even `__attribute__((always_inline))` doesn't help performance much; passing args still results in reload/store to make another copy).

**Don't benchmark debug builds, it's useless and tells you *very* little about
`-O3` performance.**  (You might also want to use `-O3  -march=native -ffast-math`, depending on your use-case.)