# what happened if store with memory_order_acquire

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-barriers, stdatomic

as we know：
load with memory_order_acquire,
store with memory_order_release
However, 
I found with gcc4.8.2, open -O2, a compile error throwed,
   /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/atomic:199:9: error: invalid memory model for '__atomic_store'
but if close -O2, the error disappeared

further more, if with gcc8.3.0, the error would throwed even when with -O2

So what happend? how to explain this?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of code that fails?  And does "open -O2" mean with the option, or without it?  "Open/closed" isn't standard terminology for command line options.

Comment: from [std::atomic<T>::store](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/store) - *order must be one of `memory_order_relaxed`, `memory_order_release` or `memory_order_seq_cst`. Otherwise the behavior is undefined.* if look for concrete lib implementation (i look for msvc not gcc) - [`_Check_store_memory_order`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/atomic#L151) and [store](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/atomic#L419) - visible that `_INVALID_MEMORY_ORDER` case executed. which expand to nothing or to `_STL_REPORT_ERROR("Invalid memory order")`

Comment: @Nate Eldredge  open -O2 I mean with this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without optimization, the `order` isn't visible as a compile-time constant to a compiler built-in, and GCC just treats runtime-variable orders as `seq_cst`** (instead of branching on the value to skip an `mfence`).  Optimization is required for constant-propagation to make the illegal `order` visible to the compiler logic that checks it, and give you the expected error.

`std::atomic<T>::store()` is a function written in C++ which takes an `order` arg and passes that variable to the GNU C builtin `__atomic_store`.

Without optimization, constant-propagation doesn't happen.  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point).  Even `__attribute__((always_inline))` doesn't make the compiler *optimize* when inlining, it just avoids having an actual function call.  [Why is this C++ wrapper class not being inlined away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073295/why-is-this-c-wrapper-class-not-being-inlined-away/54074497#54074497)

If you look at the resulting un-optimized asm, there's even a non-inlined call to `std::operator&(std::memory_order, std::__memory_order_modifier)` https://godbolt.org/z/dhViAG.  But the atomic store itself inlined.

Comment: thanks so much, but I can not understand  "instead of branching on the value to skip an mfence", why gcc just treats runtime-variable orders as seq_cst?

Comment: @Chanjun: because `seq_cst` is always strong enough, and runtime-variable `order` is basically never used in source code.  So this only happens with un-optimized code, and it's a simple way to make less bloated asm.  It's not worth making the compiler more complicated to do anything else because it only affects un-optimized code, and un-optimized code doesn't matter.  Stop wasting your time looking at it, unless you want to know about GCC internals.

Comment: GCC unoptimized code generated is often ugly, but with `std::atomic`, ouch. It's really ugly.

Comment: @curiousguy: templated C++ code is usually a nightmare without optimization.  C11 `stdatomic` is IIRC not much worse than you'd expect most of the time.